# Can RVM find versions of ruby it did not install?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm running os x lion. A version of ruby was installed when I installed the OS. I then installed RVM and then installed ruby 1.9.2 and made it the default for new shells.

```
Default Ruby (for new shells)

   ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]
```

What happend to the older version of Ruby that was already on my system and how can I remove it since  RVM doesn't see it?

When I try to use the new hash syntax in code written in textmate  or sublime text 2 it fails. When the same code is run in the shell it works. So how do I make ruby 1.9.2 the only ruby installed on my system?

Comment: The system Ruby is in `/usr/bin/ruby`. Do not remove it. If you want to use it again, you can `rvm use system`.

Answer (score 4):

You do NOT want to uninstall the system Ruby. It is required for a lot of applications (including RVM) to function properly.

If you want applications like Textmate or Sublime Text to use a different version of Ruby, you can update their individual configuration settings to set the path to the Ruby binary you wish to use.

Answer (score 2):

Since those apps don't run `ruby` from the shell like you do they don't work seamlessly with RVM. Fortunately RVM's web site has instructions on [integrating RVM with TextMate](http://beginrescueend.com/integration/textmate/). You shouldn't have trouble applying the same process for Sublime Text 2 but if you do the web does not want for [tutorials on the topic](http://www.google.com/search?q=sublime+text+2+rvm).

Answer (score 0):

Also, RVM is not responsible for any ruby it didn't install. the only other ruby it gives access to is the system ruby, and there it doesn't do gemsets etc. (This is also due to systems like debian that specifically block off things like gem update --system so you don't poison the package that was installed. RVM protects from that as well)